# Serving polylines as raster tiles

Tags: raster, leaflet, tile-server

I have a (big) list of polylines that I would like to serve as raster tiles to be consumed by Leaflet in a format such as `https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`. The tiles will only be used as overlay, so no additional OSM data needs to be displayed.

What tools/processes (e.g. for converting and tile serving) are suited for this setup?

Comment: To avoid rasterization one possibility would be to convert polylines (in GeoJSON format) to vector tiles with Mapbox [Tippecanoe](https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe) and then render vector tiles in Leaflet with the [Leaflet.VectorGrid](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid) plugin.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Might be a bit tricky, as I don't control the application running leaflet and thus can't enable plugins. What tile server would you recommend for serving the vector tiles?

Comment: Sorry, server side is not my forte, but I would say any server is OK, since vector tiles have the same tile structure as raster tiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that was good enough for me:

1. Convert from GeoJSON to MBTiles via [Tippecanoe](https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe)
2. Serve the MBTiles via [Tileserver-GL](https://github.com/maptiler/tileserver-gl) which gives endpoints for raster *and* vector tiles.